# Recursively search a sub-string in array with strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, recursion

For the next array, the keys of each sub-array indicates the node-id (0) and category name (1) .
What i am trying to do is to find the parent node-id for each sub-category.

For example, the parent id for '3968976031' is '10176091' and the parent id for '3968980031' is '3968977031'.
In order to define who is the parent, we have to look at the category :
The parent of `Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung` is `Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren`

Any form of help will be much appreciated.

```
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "10176091"
        [1]=>
        string(48) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "3968976031"
        [1]=>
        string(68) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "3968977031"
        [1]=>
        string(88) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "3968978031"
        [1]=>
        string(99) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung/Bettbezüge"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "3968979031"
        [1]=>
        string(99) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung/Bettdecken"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "3968980031"
        [1]=>
        string(104) "Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung/Bettwäsche-Sets"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Will the array entries always be ordered in categorically-descending order as shown here?

Comment: yes, it will follow this pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a foreach :

```
$seenCategories = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $subArray) {

    $id = $subArray[0];
    $category = $subArray[1]; 
    // $category = Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung/Bettwäsche-Sets

    // saving category in order to be found as a parent in the future
    $seenCategories[$category] = $id;

    // parsing category in order to find parent
    $categoriesList = explode('/', $category);
    $nbSubCategories = count($categoriesList);
    // we remove the last subcategory (Bettwäsche-Sets) to find the parent
    unset($categoriesList[$nbSubCategories-1]);
    $parentCategory = implode("/", $categoriesList);
    // $parentCategory = Küche & Haushalt/Heimtextilien, Bad- & Bettwaren/Babybettausstattung/Babybettausstattung

    // deleted loop due to performence leak
    /*$parentId = null;
    for($testingKey = $key-1; $testingKey >= 0; $testingKey--) {
        if($parentCategory == $myArray[$testingKey][1]) {
            // we found the parent
            $parentId = $myArray[$testingKey][0];
            // let's exit loop
            break;
        }
    }*/

    // performence improvement
    // if we've already seen the parent, we get its id (we suppose a parent can't be after a children)
    if(array_key_exists($parentCategory, $seenCategories) {
        $parentId = $seenCategories[$parentCategory];
    } else {
        $parentId = null;
    }

    echo "id of item : $id, category : $category, parentId : $parentId";
}
```

**EDIT :**

Improved performences according to Mr.DOS's comment. Thanks.

Comment: i am deeply sorry, i mislead you. the edit was not correct.  the parent id for '3968980031' is '3968977031' . you can check by analyzing the strings by breaking the '/'

Comment: @MihaiGabrielZamfir I edited my answer so we are looking for the direct parent. If it is missing, the id will be null

Comment: This solution involves looping over the entire array once for each element in the array. From an algorithmic analysis standpoint, it's called an O(n^2) solution. It works, but it's not as efficient as it could be. A major improvement would be to build an associative array with subcategory names as keys and node IDs as values, then after determining the parent category, use it to perform a lookup on that map instead of iterating through the whole array again.

Comment: @Mr.DOS I improved performences, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the child always follows the parent and the array only ever contains one branch of the tree, we can very easily get the parent ID of each subcategory based on its predecessor in the array. This approach is significantly more efficient than @Random's solution as it does not require making a second pass over the entire array for each subarray, and it involves no string manipulation.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($categories); $i++)
{
    $id = $categories[$i][0];
    $name = $categories[$i][1];
    $parent_id = $categories[$i - 1][0];

    printf('ID: %s; category: %s; parent ID: %s',
           $id, $name, $parent_id);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that there may be multiple children of the same parent, so `$i-1` may be a brother... you have to look at the category (which contains / for each node)

Comment: In that case, a variant on @Random's solution is about the best you can do. I'll leave another comment on that indicating a possibly significant improvement.